# How do I solve for the velocities in the matrices?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I derived four equations and put them into their matrix form. How can I solve for velocity with them?

> $$
> \begin{split}
>  m_s \ddot{x}_s + R_{s1}\dot{x}_s + R_{2s}\left( \dot{x}_s  - \dot{x}_m\right) + K_{s1}x_s + K_{s2} \left( x_s - x_m \right)  &=& P_0 \\
>  m_m \ddot{x}_m + R_{m}\dot{x}_m - R_{2s}\left( \dot{x}_s  - \dot{x}_m\right) + K_{m}x_m - K_{s2} \left( x_s - x_m \right)&=&0 \\
> \dot{x}_s - v_s&=& 0 \\
> \dot{x}_m - v_m &=& 0
> \end{split}
> $$
>
> $$
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> 1 &0 & 0 &0 \\
> 0 &1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & m_s &0 \\
> 0 &0 & 0 & m_s \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> \dot{x}_s \\ \dot{x}_m \\ \dot{v}_s \\ \dot{v}_m
> \end{array}
> \right]
> +
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 &0 & - 1& 0 \\
> 0& 0 &0 & -1 \\
> K_{s1} + K_{s2} & -K_{s2} & R_{s1} + R_{s2} & -R_{s2} \\
> -K_{s2} & K_{m} + K_{s2} & - R_{s2} & R_m + R_{s2}
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> {x}_s \\ {x}_m \\ {v}_s \\ {v}_m
> \end{array}
> \right] = 
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \sin{\omega t}
> $$

[Equations & Matrix Equivalents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cEJq.jpg)

Comment: where did the $\sin\omega t$ come from?

Comment: P0 is equal to 1 sin(omega t). It is a forcing function. The equations depict a forced vibration coupled mass harmonic oscillator.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve for velocities"? What is given, and what you want to find?

Comment: The terms [x(dot)s; x(dot)m; v(dot)s; v(dot)m], I want to know how to arrange these matrices to solve for them. I am writing a script in Matlab, but do not know how to manipulate these matrices to solve for the terms.

Comment: How much do you know about solving ODEs (numerically)?

Comment: Divide the last two equations by $m_s$, so you obtain a vector in the left part. Let $x$ be a full state vector, as in the answer below. Then your system is given by $\dot{x} = Ax + B u$, where $u=\sin(\omega t)$. Then given $x$ you can compute $\dot{x}$. If you want to solve this ODE numerically, check the Matlab function lsim.

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&:=\mathbf{x}(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_s & x_m & v_s & v_m
\end{bmatrix}^T,\\
A&:=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 & - 1& 0 \\
0& 0 &0 & -1 \\
\frac{K_{s1} + K_{s2}}{m_s} & -\frac{K_{s2}}{m_s} & \frac{R_{s1} + R_{s2}}{m_s} & -\frac{R_{s2}}{m_s} \\
-\frac{K_{s2}}{m_s} & \frac{K_m + K_{s2}}{m_s} & - \frac{R_{s2}}{m_s} & \frac{R_m + R_{s2}}{m_s}
\end{bmatrix},\\
\mathbf{c}&:=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac1{m_s} &0
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

So your system is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbf{x}+A\mathbf{x}=\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{c}.
$$
Left multiply by $\exp(At)$ gives
$$
\underbrace{\exp(At)\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}+\exp(At)A\mathbf{x}}_{=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[\exp(At)\mathbf{x}]}=\exp(At)\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{c}
$$
So
$$
\exp(At)\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}(0)+\left(\int_0^t\exp(A\tau)\sin(\omega\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau\right)\mathbf{c}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\exp(-At)\,\mathbf{x}(0)+\exp(-At)\left(\int_0^t\exp(A\tau)\sin(\omega\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau\right)\mathbf{c}.
$$